# Problem with imports and exports when running build command

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, webstorm

I can't understand the problem with imports and exports when running the specified command, there are no errors in WebStorm.
Locally, everything works, but when I want to deploy to Verсel, everything breaks.

I am getting the following error:
[image]

Here's an example of a component SliderDual:

```
import React, {
  FC,
  LegacyRef,
  MutableRefObject,
  ReactNode,
  RefObject,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";

interface SliderDualProps {
  max?: number;
  min?: number;
  onChange?: (value: {
    min: number | undefined;
    max: number | undefined;
  }) => void;
  step?: number;
  tooltipChildren?: ReactNode;
}

const SliderDual: FC<SliderDualProps> = ({
  max = 100,
  min = 0,
  onChange,
  step,
  tooltipChildren,
}: SliderDualProps) => {

...

export {SliderDual};
```

This is how I import:

```
import {SliderDual} from "@/core/ui/components";
```

And finally my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Background:**

This was a project in JS, and I rewrote everything in TS. There is a TS file where I have only components, with a small number of pages. And I decided to refactor the main website, which was in JS.

What I have already done:

1. I checked all the imports and exports. Everything works fine in the neighboring project with exactly the same components and settings.
2. I deleted all the npm modules and reinstalled them.
3. I cleared the IDE cache, restarted the IDE and the computer.
4. I tried creating a new TS project from scratch and moving all the folders and files there. Everything runs locally, but the "build" command produces the same results.

It is possible that there are errors somewhere in the following:

[image]
[image]

At the very beginning, after I created a new TS file to modify all the components, I copied and pasted them into the old project. However, I noticed that for some reason, the old files are still being saved in the IDE. It's possible that they are not affecting anything because they are not part of the project as indicated.

Comment: Try to import using relative path. Replace `@/...` with the relative path and see if it works. The IDE knows how to import via the "path" aliases(`@/`) because typescript supports it. But typescript compilation wont handle this on its own, so this is why the import is not resolved. I suspect it's because your builder is not configured to take the "path" configuration in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I ended up creating a new project, in which everything will have to be transferred step by step, since I cannot understand what the errors are, because everything is correct with imports, exports and config. As a result, somewhere a small mistake that breaks everything, and which I cannot find